# Background repeat on y-axis when viewed in mobile

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I can't get my background image to repeat on the y-axis when it is viewed on a mobile device. currently when on desktop the page can't scroll and the background image fills the screen. but if you move to tablet or mobile you need to scroll and the image is not repeating. My current code isn't much:

```
  body {
    background-image: url("../assets/BG.png");
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    background-position: center center;
    margin-top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
    margin: 0;
  }
```

Any help would be great.

Gif of issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PaWQI.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

erase `background-size: cover;` from that rule - this will always fill the full body element, also the part that appears when scrolling. Add `background-size: 100% auto;` instead and change the position to `background-position: left top` to make sure the image covers the complete width, starting from the upper left edge.

(BTW, `position: absolute;` for the `body` element is rather strange)

Here's a snippet that demonstrates it with a placeholder image:

```css
 body {
    background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/600/100/food");
    background-size: 100% auto;
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    background-position: left top;
    margin-top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
    margin: 0;
  }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying, i have done what you said but the image isnt repeating down the y axis still

Comment: Also, I added `position: absolute;` because when scrolling and the view bounces back there is a small gap left at the top of the page without it

Comment: Look at the snippet I added - it works. Maybe you forgot to erase *all* the prefixed `background-size: cover` settings.

Comment: concerning that "gap" (re position: absolute): Just add `html, body { margin: 0 }` to avoid the default margin.

Comment: Im still getting the same issue. If i add `background-attachment: fixed;` as a work around this gif shows whats happening. https://imgur.com/a/jX19E I think this is the same reason your answer isnt working but i dont know why. Any ideas?

Comment: I would erase `height: 100%` and `position: absolute`

Comment: Lol, that fixed it for mobile but now leaves a thick black line at the bottom in desktop

Comment: then add `min-height: 100%` instead

Comment: That was it, with `position: absolute`. Thank you so much for all your help